# can't open URL in flutter

Tags: flutter, url-launcher

> **UPDATED**

After `Debug` I checked that `Facebook url` is `null` but when I login i can see user has `FB` url then why it giving me `null`

Here I'm attaching image of my response. Kindly help me on this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xWwFb.png)

I've saved user `Facebook` link but can't open it in `browser`. If I write simple url like `https://...` then it open.  I'm using `url_launcher` package.

Here Is my code

> Model

```
Data dataFromJson(String str) => Data.fromJson(json.decode(str));

String dataToJson(Data data) => json.encode(data.toJson());

class Data {
  Data({
    this.id,
    this.username,
    this.type,
    this.customerId,
    this.lang,
    this.countryId,
    this.email,
    this.firstName,
    this.lastName,
    this.phone,
    this.address,
    this.location,
    this.dob,
    this.sex,
    this.city,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
    this.idPhoto,
    this.accessToken,
    this.accessTokenEnd,
    this.roleId,
    this.verified,
    this.verificationCode,
    this.passwordCode,
    this.fcmToken,
    this.mobile,
    this.bio,
    this.photo,
    this.lat,
    this.lon,
    this.verifiedSponsor,
    this.requests,
    this.isActive,
    this.categoryId,
    this.companyName,
    this.tradeLicense,
    this.field,
    this.workTime,
    this.facebook,
    this.linkedIn,
    this.instagram,
    this.whatsApp,
    this.fbId,
    this.googleToken,
    this.facebookToken,
    this.facebookId,
    this.googleId,
    this.balance,
    this.photos,
    this.role,
  });

  Data.fromJson(dynamic json) {
    id = json['id'];
    username = json['username'];
    type = json['type'];
    customerId = json['customer_id'];
    lang = json['lang'];
    countryId = json['country_id'];
    email = json['email'];
    firstName = json['first_name'];
    lastName = json['last_name'];
    phone = json['phone'];
    address = json['address'];
    location = json['location'];
    dob = json['dob'];
    sex = json['sex'];
    city = json['city'];
    createdAt = json['created_at'];
    updatedAt = json['updated_at'];
    idPhoto = json['id_photo'];
    accessToken = json['access_token'];
    accessTokenEnd = json['access_token_end'];
    roleId = json['role_id'];
    verified = json['verified'];
    verificationCode = json['verification_code'];
    passwordCode = json['password_code'];
    fcmToken = json['fcm_token'];
    mobile = json['mobile'];
    bio = json['bio'];
    photo = json['photo'];
    lat = json['lat'];
    lon = json['lon'];
    verifiedSponsor = json['verified_sponsor'];
    requests = json['requests'];
    isActive = json['is_active'];
    categoryId = json['category_id'];
    companyName = json['company_name'];
    tradeLicense = json['trade_license'];
    field = json['field'];
    workTime = json['work_time'];
    facebook:
    json["facebook"];
    linkedIn:
    json["linkedIn"];
    instagram:
    json["instagram"];
    whatsApp:
    json["whatsApp"];
    fbId:
    json["fb_id"];
    googleToken:
    json["google_token"];
    facebookToken:
    json["facebook_token"];
    facebookId:
    json["facebook_id"];
    googleId:
    json["google_id"];
    if (json['balance'] != null) {
      balance = [];
      json['balance'].forEach((v) {
        balance?.add(Balance.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
    if (json['photos'] != null) {
      photos = [];
      json['photos'].forEach((v) {
        photos?.add(v);
      });
    }
    role = json['role'] != null ? Role.fromJson(json['role']) : null;
  }

  int? id;
  String? username;
  int? type;
  int? customerId;
  int? lang;
  int? countryId;
  String? email;
  String? firstName;
  dynamic lastName;
  String? phone;
  String? address;
  dynamic location;
  dynamic dob;
  dynamic sex;
  dynamic city;
  String? createdAt;
  String? updatedAt;
  dynamic idPhoto;
  dynamic accessToken;
  dynamic accessTokenEnd;
  int? roleId;
  int? verified;
  String? verificationCode;
  String? passwordCode;
  String? fcmToken;
  String? mobile;
  String? bio;
  String? photo;
  String? lat;
  String? lon;
  int? verifiedSponsor;
  int? requests;
  int? isActive;
  int? categoryId;
  dynamic companyName;
  dynamic tradeLicense;
  dynamic field;
  dynamic workTime;
  String? facebook;
  String? linkedIn;
  String? instagram;
  String? whatsApp;
  dynamic fbId;
  dynamic googleToken;
  dynamic facebookToken;
  dynamic facebookId;
  dynamic googleId;
  List<Balance>? balance;
  List<dynamic>? photos;
  Role? role;

  Data copyWith({
    int? id,
    String? username,
    int? type,
    int? customerId,
    int? lang,
    int? countryId,
    String? email,
    String? firstName,
    dynamic lastName,
    String? phone,
    String? address,
    dynamic location,
    dynamic dob,
    dynamic sex,
    dynamic city,
    String? createdAt,
    String? updatedAt,
    dynamic idPhoto,
    dynamic accessToken,
    dynamic accessTokenEnd,
    int? roleId,
    int? verified,
    String? verificationCode,
    String? passwordCode,
    dynamic fcmToken,
    String? mobile,
    dynamic bio,
    dynamic photo,
    dynamic lat,
    dynamic lon,
    int? verifiedSponsor,
    int? requests,
    int? isActive,
    int? categoryId,
    dynamic companyName,
    dynamic tradeLicense,
    dynamic field,
    dynamic workTime,
    String? facebook,
    String? linkedIn,
    String? instagram,
    String? whatsApp,
    dynamic fbId,
    dynamic googleToken,
    dynamic facebookToken,
    dynamic facebookId,
    dynamic googleId,
    List<Balance>? balance,
    List<dynamic>? photos,
    Role? role,
  }) =>
      Data(
        id: id ?? this.id,
        username: username ?? this.username,
        type: type ?? this.type,
        customerId: customerId ?? this.customerId,
        lang: lang ?? this.lang,
        countryId: countryId ?? this.countryId,
        email: email ?? this.email,
        firstName: firstName ?? this.firstName,
        lastName: lastName ?? this.lastName,
        phone: phone ?? this.phone,
        address: address ?? this.address,
        location: location ?? this.location,
        dob: dob ?? this.dob,
        sex: sex ?? this.sex,
        city: city ?? this.city,
        createdAt: createdAt ?? this.createdAt,
        updatedAt: updatedAt ?? this.updatedAt,
        idPhoto: idPhoto ?? this.idPhoto,
        accessToken: accessToken ?? this.accessToken,
        accessTokenEnd: accessTokenEnd ?? this.accessTokenEnd,
        roleId: roleId ?? this.roleId,
        verified: verified ?? this.verified,
        verificationCode: verificationCode ?? this.verificationCode,
        passwordCode: passwordCode ?? this.passwordCode,
        fcmToken: fcmToken ?? this.fcmToken,
        mobile: mobile ?? this.mobile,
        bio: bio ?? this.bio,
        photo: photo ?? this.photo,
        lat: lat ?? this.lat,
        lon: lon ?? this.lon,
        verifiedSponsor: verifiedSponsor ?? this.verifiedSponsor,
        requests: requests ?? this.requests,
        isActive: isActive ?? this.isActive,
        categoryId: categoryId ?? this.categoryId,
        companyName: companyName ?? this.companyName,
        tradeLicense: tradeLicense ?? this.tradeLicense,
        field: field ?? this.field,
        workTime: workTime ?? this.workTime,
        facebook: facebook ?? this.facebook,
        linkedIn: linkedIn ?? this.linkedIn,
        instagram: instagram ?? this.instagram,
        whatsApp: whatsApp ?? this.whatsApp,
        fbId: fbId ?? this.fbId,
        googleToken: googleToken ?? this.googleToken,
        facebookToken: facebookToken ?? this.facebookToken,
        facebookId: facebookId ?? this.facebookId,
        googleId: googleId ?? this.googleId,
        balance: balance ?? this.balance,
        photos: photos ?? this.photos,
        role: role ?? this.role,
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final map = <String, dynamic>{};
    map['id'] = id;
    map['username'] = username;
    map['type'] = type;
    map['customer_id'] = customerId;
    map['lang'] = lang;
    map['country_id'] = countryId;
    map['email'] = email;
    map['first_name'] = firstName;
    map['last_name'] = lastName;
    map['phone'] = phone;
    map['address'] = address;
    map['location'] = location;
    map['dob'] = dob;
    map['sex'] = sex;
    map['city'] = city;
    map['created_at'] = createdAt;
    map['updated_at'] = updatedAt;
    map['id_photo'] = idPhoto;
    map['access_token'] = accessToken;
    map['access_token_end'] = accessTokenEnd;
    map['role_id'] = roleId;
    map['verified'] = verified;
    map['verification_code'] = verificationCode;
    map['password_code'] = passwordCode;
    map['fcm_token'] = fcmToken;
    map['mobile'] = mobile;
    map['bio'] = bio;
    map['photo'] = photo;
    map['lat'] = lat;
    map['lon'] = lon;
    map['verified_sponsor'] = verifiedSponsor;
    map['requests'] = requests;
    map['is_active'] = isActive;
    map['category_id'] = categoryId;
    map['company_name'] = companyName;
    map['trade_license'] = tradeLicense;
    map['field'] = field;
    map['work_time'] = workTime;
    map['facebook'] = facebook;
    map['linkedIn'] = linkedIn;
    map['instagram'] = instagram;
    map['whatsApp'] = whatsApp;
    map['fb_id'] = fbId;
    map['google_token'] = googleToken;
    map['facebook_token'] = facebookToken;
    map['facebook_id'] = facebookId;
    map['google_id'] = googleId;
    return map;
  }
}
```

> User Contact Page

```
class ContactUser extends StatefulWidget {
  final Data usersDetail;

  const ContactUser({Key? key, required this.usersDetail}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ContactUser> createState() => _ContactUserState();
}

class _ContactUserState extends State<ContactUser> {
 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: AppColors.fBackgroundColor,
      appBar: AppBar(
          leading: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded, size: Dimensions.height30, color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor),
          ),
          actions: [
            Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: Dimensions.width15),
                child: ImageIcon(const AssetImage('assets/images/notif.png'), size: Dimensions.height40, color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor)),
          ],
          elevation: 0.0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: Dimensions.height200,
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width15),
              child: Card(
                clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
                shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius10),
                ),
                child: CachedNetworkImage(
                    placeholder: (context, url) => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
                    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => const Icon(Icons.error),
                    imageUrl: widget.usersDetail.photo ?? "",
                    fit: BoxFit.fill),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height20),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width15),
              child: BigText(text: widget.usersDetail.firstName ?? ""),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width15),
              child: SmallText(text: widget.usersDetail.bio ?? "", align: TextAlign.justify, color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height10),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.height10),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  Icon(Icons.location_on_outlined, size: Dimensions.height20, color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor),
                  SizedBox(width: Dimensions.width10),
                  SmallText(text: widget.usersDetail.address ?? "", color: Colors.grey)
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height20),

            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width10),
              child: BigText(text: "User Rating"),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height10),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width10),
              child: BigText(text: "3.5"),
            ),

         
            SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height20),
            Center(child: BigText(text: LanguageStringKeys.instance.ContactUs.tr, color: Colors.grey)),
            SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height20),
            Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
              children: [
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      final url = Uri.parse(widget.usersDetail.facebook ?? "");
                      if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                        await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault);
                      } else {
                        Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("User didn't added his contact yet", context);
                      }
                    },
                    child: buildContacts(FontAwesomeIcons.facebook)),
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      final url = Uri.parse(widget.usersDetail.firstName ?? "");
                      if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                        await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault);
                      } else {
                        Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("User didn't added his contact yet", context);
                      }
                    },
                    child: buildContacts(FontAwesomeIcons.linkedin)),
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      final url = Uri.parse(widget.usersDetail.firstName ?? "");
                      if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                        await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault);
                      } else {
                        Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("User didn't added his contact yet", context);
                      }
                    },
                    child: buildContacts(FontAwesomeIcons.instagram)),
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      final url = Uri.parse(widget.usersDetail.firstName ?? "");
                      if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                        await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault);
                      } else {
                        Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("User didn't added his contact yet", context);
                      }
                    },
                    child: buildContacts(FontAwesomeIcons.whatsapp)),
                InkWell(
                    onTap: () async {
                      final url = Uri.parse("tel:${widget.usersDetail.phone ?? ""}");
                      if (await canLaunchUrl(url)) {
                        await launchUrl(url, mode: LaunchMode.platformDefault);
                      } else {
                        Utils.flushBarErrorMessage("User didn't added his contact yet", context);
                      }
                    },
                    child: buildContacts(FontAwesomeIcons.phone)),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ));
  }

  Widget buildContacts(IconData icon) {
    return Container(
        width: Dimensions.width50,
        height: Dimensions.height50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius10 + 5), color: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor),
        child: Icon(icon));
  }
}
```

> Here are my links saved

```
class SocialLinks extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(Map<String, String>) callBack;

  const SocialLinks(this.callBack, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SocialLinks> createState() => _SocialLinksState();
}

class _SocialLinksState extends State<SocialLinks> {

  var facebookLinkController = TextEditingController();
  var linkedInLinkController = TextEditingController();
  var instagramLinkController = TextEditingController();
  var whatsAppController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      facebookLinkController.text = Get.put(AppController()).loginResponse?.data?.user?.facebook ?? "";
      linkedInLinkController.text = Get.put(AppController()).loginResponse?.data?.user?.linkedIn ?? "";
      instagramLinkController.text = Get.put(AppController()).loginResponse?.data?.user?.instagram ?? "";
      whatsAppController.text = Get.put(AppController()).loginResponse?.data?.user?.whatsApp ?? "";
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BackgroundImage(
      image: 'assets/images/bgHome.png',
      child: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(Dimensions.height56),
            child: const AppBarMain(
              iconColor: AppColors.fIconsAndTextColor,
              text: Text('Add Your Social Contacts'),
            )),
        body: Center(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            physics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
            child: Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: Dimensions.width20, vertical: Dimensions.width10),
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  AppTextField(
                    textController: facebookLinkController,
                    labelText: 'Facebook Link',
                    inputType: TextInputType.url,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height15),
                  AppTextField(
                    textController: linkedInLinkController,
                    labelText: 'LinkedIn Link',
                    inputType: TextInputType.url,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height15),
                  AppTextField(
                    textController: instagramLinkController,
                    labelText: 'Instagram Link',
                    inputType: TextInputType.url,
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height15),
                  AppTextField(
                    textController: whatsAppController,
                    labelText: 'WhatsApp Number',
                    hint: 'Type your Number with Country Code',
                    inputType: TextInputType.phone,
                  ),
                 
                  SizedBox(height: Dimensions.height15),
                  ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      // pushNewScreen(context, screen: const UserProfile());
                      Map<String, String> data = {};

                      if (facebookLinkController.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                        data["facebook"] = facebookLinkController.text.trim();
                      }
                      if (linkedInLinkController.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                        data["linkedIn"] = linkedInLinkController.text.trim();
                      }
                      if (instagramLinkController.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                        data["instagram"] = instagramLinkController.text.trim();
                      }
                      if (whatsAppController.text.trim().isNotEmpty) {
                        data["whatsApp"] = whatsAppController.text.trim();
                      }
                      Provider.of<UserProfileService>(context, listen: false).updateUserProfile(context, data, {});
                      /*widget.callBack(data);*/
                      Get.back();
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      primary: Colors.white,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(Dimensions.radius10)),
                      minimumSize: Size.fromHeight(Dimensions.height40),
                    ),
                    child: const SmallText(text: 'Save', color: Colors.grey),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: add this code in try-catch block and see what error you are getting.

Comment: I/UrlLauncher(16110): component name for  is null

Comment: when i try to write like this `"https:${widget.usersDetail.facebook??""}"` it open but a white screen

Comment: but if i try to open `telephone` it open like `final url = Uri.parse("tel:${widget.usersDetail.phone ?? ""}");` but not https

Comment: if you `print("https:${widget.usersDetail.facebook??""}")` - what do you see?

Comment: try unrestricting the javascripts.

Comment: i only see `https:`

Comment: so don't be surprised it does not open anything

Comment: so how to open then?

Comment: how to open what? your `widget.usersDetail.facebook` is null, so what do you want to open?

Comment: I had the error too some time ago, I changed the launch mode to external application and the white screen has gone away

Comment: @pskink bro it is saved, I get the response where Facebook  link is saved.

Comment: please update show the code you get user data from response

Comment: @manhtuan21 kindly check it now